# Which is better, the Meowmere or the Last Prism?

Tags: terraria

I was wondering which of these two Moon Lord drops is better. I have seen videos involving the two and I just can't figure out which is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly subjective to what class you are interested in using.

[Last Prism](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Last_Prism) probably has the higher damage per second (DPS) of the two weapons, but it uses mana. Straight from the wiki:

> However, due to the high mana cost (12 mana 6 times per second when fully charged = 72 mana per second), players will struggle to maintain the beam for more than 5-6 seconds. A Mana Flower, Nebula armor, and a large supply of Super Mana Potions may be required for continuous use.

But if you have chosen the mage route through the game, you are probably well prepared with the appropriate [accessories](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Accessory) (reduced mana usage, increased magic damage, etc) to let you use Last Prism effectively.

[Meowmere](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meowmere), on the other hand, is a (semi-)melee weapon, with higher base damage than the mini beams (200>100) but lower base damage than the super beam (600>200) and lower overall DPS. It does have the advantage of shooting bouncing projectiles, making it, in my opinion, one of the best melee weapons.
Once again, with the correct accessories, it can achieve crazy high damage output.

Honestly, which one of the two weapons you choose is mainly up to individual preference and play style. Personally, I prefer Meowmere because with it I don't have to worry about mana constraints. However, both weapons are obviously high-tier and completely viable for use.